# JavaFX ListView-Update selected cell view using cellfactory

Tags: listview, javafx, cell

Here i have created a custom listview using cellfactory and updated with custom nodes,but i need to change the graphic(contents) when i select a cell. i know we use css to change the appearance of selected cell,but here i would like to update graphic(content) of selected cell in listview **not background color or text color**.Is there any way to do like that??

normally my listview hierarchy is like this

**Hbox->Label1,Label2**

but when i select any cell it should(only selected cell) update like this

**Hbox->Label1,Label2,Labe3,Label4,Button1**

Here is my code

```
Callback<ListView<CustomListView>, ListCell<CustomListView>> cellFactory = new Callback<ListView<CustomListView>, ListCell<CustomListView>>() 
{ 

    @Override
        public ListCell<CustomListView> call(ListView<CustomListView> arg0) 
    {

        cell = new ListCell<CustomListView>() 
        {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(CustomListView item, boolean bln) 
            {

                super.updateItem(item, bln);
                            if(item == null)
                            {
                                setGraphic(null);
                                setText(null);
                                return;
                            }
                            else
                {
                    //Normally my listview will display like this(An HBOX with 2 Labels)

                    HBox h1 =new HBox();
                    Label itemName=new Label("item1);
                    Label price=new Label("100");
                    h1.getchildren.addAll(itemName,price);
                    setGraphic(h1);

                    //When i select any cell it should  display like this((An Hbox with 4 Labels(selected cell only,remaining cells in first format))

                    HBox h2 =new HBox();
                    Label itemName=new Label("item1);
                    Label price=new Label("100");
                    Label Discount=new Label("50%");
                    Label Tax=new Label("5%");  
                    Button b1=new Button();
                    h2.getchildren.addAll(itemName,price,discount,tax,b1); 
                    setGraphic(h2);

                    //i have tried with these lines of codes but it does not working properly
                    cell.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                    if(isNowSelected==false)//not selected
                   {
                        //load hbox1
                    }
                    else //selected
                    { 
                        //load hbox2
                    }



                }
                             }
        }; return cell;
    }
};
    listView.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Cell`s are designed to prevent unnecessary node creation when different items are displayed. For this reason you should not recreate the nodes every time `updateItem` is called. Furthermore you never remove the listener from the `selected` property which means there could be many `HBox`es that are updated, which will never be visible again. Also there are quite some errors in your code that prevent it from compiling...

The following code should work though:

```
listView.setCellFactory(l -> new ListCell<CustomListView >() {

    // create all nodes that could be displayed
    private final Label itemName = new Label("item1");
    private final Label price = new Label("100");
    private final HBox contentContainer = new HBox();

    private final Label discount = new Label("50%");
    private final Label tax = new Label("5%");
    private final Button button = new Button();

    {
        // update HBox every time the selection changes
        selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            CustomListView item = getItem();
            if (!isEmpty() && item != null) {
                updateItemSelection(item, newValue);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(CustomListView  item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(contentContainer);
            updateItemSelection(item, isSelected());
        }
    }

    private void updateItemSelection(CustomListView item, boolean selected) {
        // update for HBox for non-empty cells based on selection
        if (selected) {
            contentContainer.getChildren().setAll(itemName, price, discount, tax, button);
        } else {
            contentContainer.getChildren().setAll(itemName, price);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: yesss its worked.The error in my code because i just modified into understandable way.Thanks lot fabian you are my hero. Can you tell me the diffrence between hbox.getchildren.addAll and hbox.getchildren.setAll as you mentioned here in your code. Thank You.

Comment: And This Code will be very usefull for those who are looking expandable listview in javafx(instead of expanding it will update the content on select item,for ex:normally it will display only item name,if you selected any cell means it will show itemname,price,etc..)

Comment: @ihsanikbal `list.setAll(someElements);` has the same effect as `list.clear(); list.addAll(someElements);` but it only triggers a single update...